# How can I use Linq to build a c# object from xml where an element has zero or more elements of the same type?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to parse an xml file that looks roughly like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<log>
    <request id="1" result="Deny">
        <user name="corp\joe"/>
        <session number="1"/>
        <file name="xyz"/>
        <policy type="default" name="Default Rules" result="Deny"/>
        <policy type="adgroup" name="Domain Users" result="Allow"/>
    </request>
        <request id="1" result="Deny">
        <user name="corp\joe"/>
        <session number="1"/>
        <file name="abc"/>
        <policy type="default" name="Default Rules" result="Deny"/>
        <policy type="device" name="laptop12" result="Deny"/>
    </request>
</log>
```

Note the presence of multiple *policy* elements per request.

Here's my code so far:

```
public class Request
{
   public int Request_id { get; set; }
   public string User_name { get; set; }
   public string Session_number { get; set; }
   public string File_name { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var xml = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\test.xml");

    var query = from c in xml.Descendants("request")
        where (String)c.Attribute("result") == "Deny"
        select new Request() {
            Request_id = (int) c.Attribute("id"),
            User_name = (string) c.Element("user").Attribute("name"),
            Session_number = (string) c.Element("session").Attribute("number"),
            File_name = (string) c.Element("file").Attribute("name"),
        };

    foreach (Request r in query.ToList()) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(r.User_name + "," + r.File_name);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to query and capture the 0+ policy elements. Should I:

- define a new class Policy {Type, Name, Result}
- add a List member to the Request class
- somehow populate this list when creating the new Request object as part of the Linq query

It's the *somehow* bit I'm stuck on. Do I need to add another Linq query within the existing Select, and if so, what would that look like? c.Descendents("policy")...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the very good track! Your points are correct. You need a `Policy` class and a `List<Policy>` property in `Request` class. With that you need a subquery in your existing query to populate them:

```
var query = from c in xml.Descendants("request")
    where (String)c.Attribute("result") == "Deny"
    select new Request() {
        Request_id = (int) c.Attribute("id"),
        User_name = (string) c.Element("user").Attribute("name"),
        Session_number = (string) c.Element("session").Attribute("number"),
        File_name = (string) c.Element("file").Attribute("name"),
        Policies = (from p in c.Elements("policy")
                    select new Policy() {
                        Type = (string) p.Attribute("type")
                        // (...)
                    }).ToList()
    };
```

Comment: Change p.Element("type") to p.Attribute("type") and I'll mark this as the best answer. Thank you!